# UIViewController's images coordinates issue in Rotation after iOS6 porting

Tags: xcode, ipad, frame, ios6, screen-rotation

I'm developing a tabbar app for iPad. 
I have a UiViewController tab with an image on top of the windows and, on rotation event I set the image frame properly.

```
img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 169); //Portrait
...
img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 169); //Landscape
```

After upgrading to iOS6, when the user makes a rotation, the image go under the navbar.

I've tried to force the y pos of the frame to 44 (0+navbar height), and this works well for the rotation, but is not ok for the first time loading because the image frame is shifted down  as if I had moved it of 88 pixels.

```
int y = 44;
if ([Functions getDeviceOrientationIsPortrait]) { //a function to retrieve the device orientation...
    img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0+y, 768, 169);
} else {
    img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0+y, 1024, 169);
}
```

Comment: It's a problem with the class MBProgressHUB. Disabling this class, all it's ok.